# Filtering RecordArray in a child route to return a RecordArray?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Im trying to my views change when a model property changes
Im not sure if I am on the right track or not, but here goes.

I have a parent resource called lunches, whose route looks like so:

```
model: function(params){
  return this.store.filter('lunch', params, this.funcAll);
}
```

and I have a child route 'served', whose route looks like so:

```
model: function(params){
  return this.modelFor('lunches').filterProperty('isServed', true);
  // as opposed to this.store.filter('lunch', this.funcFilter()})
}
```

when I use filter in the child routes, I am able to do this (I think because a filter returns a RecordArray), but this does not work for me, for another reason. Is there anyway I can have my child route return a RecordArray which is a subset of the original model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`filter` works on a collection.

```
App.ColorsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
     this.store.find('color');
    return this.store.filter('color',function(){
      return true;
    });
  }
});

App.ColorRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
    return this.store.find('color', params.id);
  },
  setupController: function(controller, model){
    this._super(controller, model);

    var cMod = this.modelFor('colors'),
    subItems = cMod.filter(function(item){
      return item.get('color').indexOf('e')>=0;

    });
    console.log(subItems.get('length'));
  }
});
```

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/OxIDiVU/858/edit

Comment: Many thanks king-pin! I figured out the mistakes I was making which are many. But thanks to you I've figured this out.